# How to create word cloud in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, tag-cloud

I want to create word cloud in android. Is there any library available in android. Please share your knowledge. How to create word cloud in android? [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't implemented following tutorial but may those links help you to do so.

1) https://sites.google.com/site/tagindemo/TagCloud

[image]

2) https://code.google.com/p/google-summer-of-code-2011-komodo-openlab/downloads/list
3) [memeplex](https://code.google.com/p/memeplex/source/browse/trunk/Android/src/kr/ac/yonsei/memeplex/view/TagCloudLayout.java?r=31)

Comment: I used google-summer code but is not rotating faster. its rotating bit slower. how to make it faster

Comment: @G.MURALIRaja, Open `TagCloudView` file. There is constructor and it has `int scrollSpeed` argument. May this change speed of scroling.

Comment: Thanks for you help.. How to make automatic scroll while focusing the view. Is it possible in this tag cloud view...

Comment: @G.MURALIRaja, I am very sorry. I haven't implemented it. Try yourself . If I will find anything interesting after **investigation** :P I will update you :)

Comment: @MuraliGanesan: Hey did you implemented auto-scrolling feature in your project. If yes then please do help me. I also want a same feature for my application.

Comment: @MuraliGanesan did you get any solution on this, bcoz i need similar solution for my question, please help. http://stackoverflow.com/q/30480541/1576416

Comment: https://github.com/kennycason/kumo this may help to others

Answer (score 0):

This [project](https://github.com/sschwieb/Cloudio/wiki/TagCloudViewer) might be interesting to you. For further information take a look at [that](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest/Cloudio)