# Android Animations

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

[image: NewsRepublic screenshot]

I would know how implement an animation like this in the following photo that is implemented in News Republic Application. Where can I start from?

Comment: means you want animation like fade in fade out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean a message cloude like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888352/how-to-create-word-cloud-in-android) ?

[image]

There is a tutorial available [here](https://sites.google.com/site/tagindemo/TagCloud)